# JQGrid POST doesn't include postData when using IE6

Tags: javascript, wcf, jqgrid, internet-explorer-6

Using Fiddler2, when using IE6, I see that the POST request does not contain the postData specified below.  I've verified path is defined at the point of JQGrid initialization.  It works fine for IE9 and Chrome.  I am calling a WCF POST service.  The call gets made without the parameter, and hangs IE6 with no response forthcoming.

Any ideas appreciated!  edit:

Latest update: RESOLVED

The issue was a side effect of my dynamic resize code;  I was resizing the grid wrapper div on window resize event, unfortunately in IE6 a content resize bubbles up to the window causing a recursion.  This has been like talking to my diary, but maybe this will help someone else along the line.

Ok, I am able to get the data back (verified via Fiddler) via a separate AJAX call, and bound to the grid using the AddJSONData() method.  The debugger pops at the end of the datatype: callback function... But if I let it continue execution, IE6 hangs at this point.  I'm still stuck on this!

```
                grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: function ()
                {
                    var ts = this,      // - cache 'this' to use later in the complete callback
                    parameters = this.p;         // - cache the grid parameters

                    $("#list")[0].addJSONData(_gridData);

                    if ($.isFunction(parameters.loadComplete))
                        parameters.loadComplete.call(ts, _gridData);

                    if (parameters.loadonce || parameters.treeGrid)
                        parameters.datatype = "local";

                    debugger;
                },
```

Chugging away at this when I can.  I wrote a test ajax call to the GetData service method, and it populated the POST data fine in the body, and returns all the grid data.  Ok, so JQGrid is NOT setting the parameters in the request body, do I have JQGrid misconfigured?  Please advise!

---

Well sure not getting much lovin'..  in the serializeGridData function, it turns out that the JSON2 stringify is treating the postData like a string?  The quotes around the key names are getting escaped:

```
IE6: "{\"path\":\"c:\\Source\\TestUpload\\Uploads\\5ec33030-ab7b-4480-9deb-3153726c1ede.xls\",\"_search\":true,\"nd\":1349365262553,\"rows\":15,\"page\":1,\"sidx\":\"IDNumber\",\"sord\":\"desc\"}"

IE9:  {"path":"c:\\Source\\TestUpload\\Uploads\\3228b61e-4f1b-4ce4-813e-10f58b1b4285.xls","_search":true,"nd":1349365395840,"rows":15,"page":1,"sidx":"IDNumber","sord":"desc"}
```

---

Ok, so I used the compose functionality of Fiddler to modify the IE6 JQGrid request, using a valid session cookie, and just adding the POST data:

```
{"path":"c:\\Source\\TestUpload\\Uploads\\cb238b83-3c6e-42c2-92be-0e8d08dd905e.xls","_search":true,"nd":1349284471504,"rows":15,"page":1,"sidx":"IDNumber","sord":"desc"}
```

...and it worked just fine.  So for some reason, JQGrid isn't populating the POST data for IE6?  Any ideas?

---

Of note is that the content-length is correct in the request header, there's just no associated POST data.  I tried setting a breakpoint in Fiddler on XMLHttpRequests, and it did not break on the JQGrid request;  it did however break as expected on the previous AJAX requests.

This is the raw header for a successful jqgrid POST request in IE9:

```
POST http://localhost/Loader.svc/GetData?_=1349274977838 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost/BulkOrderPersonalized.aspx
Accept-Language: en-US,fr;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 169
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=qlj50u45mk4f5q55izyj23us;    MerchantV2=BAEE474A47A5264EF3B3C1977173019C569F51792BEA95C1F129634F6B5E8C8475631791B382D7159E78364979FE541B9337D3C5D2B1B0563A653E6DFD738D0D291A9CFADB3555FA4E3D891BD8912D6E0F315A51E61F240F69A6CA061B6CEA17868F9D7E33C36415DEAB3EC9178A9A2748CF002B

{"path":"c:\\Source\\TestUpload\\Uploads\\b7f0ba08-c9f5-46b3-a856-dfa33410be75.xls","_search":true,"nd":1349274977961,"rows":15,"page":1,"sidx":"IDNumber","sord":"desc"}
```

This is the raw header for the POST request that hangs IE6:

```
POST http://10.8.8.72/Loader.svc/GetData?_=1349271720318 HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-us
Referer: http://10.8.8.72/BulkOrderPersonalized.aspx
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;     NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Host: 10.8.8.72
Content-Length: 169
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=5fvcrn55mrcjw145ari0h2a1;         MerchantV2=C1EB658057878B9D526DA8216B181011CA53F98BFA7A794AFFFEF7FD855E64C63244EA741FA984FDBB8699787EC387D195474B1D08F1C784E79ECC5C8F16206CE477C91891DC26673015908CBE3C012E10CB8A3DCABDC1762DD10C3D8D15ABC403C454F4231BD16F63787D6E387683F5E99634B5
```

The only relevant difference appears to be that JQGrid is not populating the POST data when using IE6.

A previous jQuery AJAX call with post data executes just fine before the JQGrid bind:

```
function GetRequestConfigs(type, issuingBank) // - get configuration objects for user; (load initially)
{
if (_configurations == null) {

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Loader.svc/GetRequestConfigurations',
        data: '{"type":"' + type + '","issuingBank":"' + issuingBank + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            _configurations = JSON.parse(response.d);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
return _configurations;
```

}

This JQGrid POST request fails:

```
grid.jqGrid({
            url: 'Loader.svc/GetData',                  // - webinvoke post method
            postData: { path: path },

            search: true,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            loadonce: true,                             // - load data once on server side, then switch to local data handling
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },

            serializeGridData: function (postData)      // - process returned object from web-invoke to json
            {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },

            jsonReader: {                                       // - map json to grid elements ( this is how the grid expects the data from the server )
                root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
                page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
                total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
            }, ...
```

Comment: Why do you bother with IE6 bugs when you can deploy Chrome Frame?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't create the requirements.